# Multiple search in database Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to query multiple condition using codeigniter but the return query not showing correct results.

```
//search
      public function search_autocomplete_album_data($data,$userid)
      {
        return $this->db->where("userid", $userid)->like('album', $data)->or_like('album_id', $data)->where("type", "music")->or_where("type", "video")->limit(5)->get("media");
      }
```

Comment: What is the value of `$data`? What data type and some typical values would help solve your problem.

Comment: What results are you getting?  You can also do `echo $this->db->last_query()` to output the last query and see how it was formed for the db engine - this might give you a clue if it's wrong for your needs